# Marriage in the UK and go back to our country

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, weddings

My fiancé and I are planning to visit the UK and get married. We both are Indian citizens. I live in India and he is in the US on an H1B visa. Can we marry in the UK and go back to our home after that?

Comment: The unexplained downvote is vexing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can, but it's a little cumbersome.

First, to visit the UK to get married, you will need a [marriage visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/marriage-visa).

The procedure for the marriage is different depending on the legal jurisdiction, whether [Northern Ireland](https://www.nidirect.gov.uk/articles/guidance-marriage-procedures-northern-ireland), [Scotland](https://www.nrscotland.gov.uk/registration/getting-married-in-scotland/how-do-i-go-about-it), or [England and Wales](https://www.gov.uk/marriages-civil-partnerships/what-you-need-to-do).

In the last case, you must stay in the country for at least one week before you can give notice, and then you must wait four weeks before getting married.  However, the four weeks [can be extended to ten weeks](https://www.gov.uk/marriages-civil-partnerships/foreign-national).  So you need to be able to afford to travel to the UK twice, or to stay there for three months.

It's probably easier to do it in the US.

Comment: *However, the four weeks can be extended to ten weeks, and it seems that it would be in your case* Why would it be? I thought that the extended notice period was for cases where the Home Office suspects a sham marriage, conducted for the purpose of obtaining a visa. In this case, there would be no reason to conduct a sham marriage, since neither party has any right to stay in the UK.

Comment: @MJeffryes fair enough.  I do not know what the criteria are for actually extending, and if the couple show an intention to settle elsewhere I suppose it's unlikely to be extended, although if it is an arranged marriage or a couple who otherwise have known each other for a short time, I imagine the probability would increase.  I based my statement on the criteria that *allow* extension (different from *requiring* it), which include not being settled in the UK.

Comment: Also, the couple will need to pass the “genuine relationship” hurdle to get the marriage visitor visa. It would be pretty perverse for the Home Office to grant the visa and then hold up the marriage on the basis of needing more evidence (although policy perversions are a speciality of UKVI).